# I encountered a statement like "char var : 3". What does this C statement do?

Tags: c, bit-fields

While going through some C code, I encountered statements like

```
char var1 : num1, char var2: num2;
```

From the context, it seems like the number i.e. `num1` is the byte size.
I am unable to find any explanation.

Comment: What compiler is this? (Vendor, OS)

Comment: Windows 7 OS, Code Blocks Compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be part of what is called a *bit-field* in the C programming language.
Bit-fields can only be declared inside a struct, e.g.

```
struct {
   unsigned int flag  : 1;    /* A one bit flag */
   unsigned int value : 5;    /* A 5 bit value */
} option;

if (option.flag == 1)
    option.value = 7;
```

About everything on bit-fields is implementation-defined. The intention is to have bit-fields arranged as compact as possible by the compiler. E.g. the above could well fit in one byte.